# How to do inner or sub-query for the same object in SOQL

Tags: sql, salesforce, inner-join, soql, in-clause

I'm facing an issue to select the value from the same object. I provided the query below.

I'm migrating a Java J2EE application to Salesforce, the below query works in my `SQL`.
I'm trying to do the same in `SOQL`, but it doesn't work.

```
 SELECT DATA1__c, TEXT__c 
     FROM PARAMETERS__c 
     WHERE ( (TYPE__c = 'ADMINISTRATEUR') 
         AND (KEY1__c LIKE 'MONTAGE%') (AND KEY2__c = '')) 
         AND (DATA1__c 
                  IN (SELECT KEY1__c 
                      FROM Parameters__c 
                      WHERE TYPE__c = 'PERE_TECHNIQUE'))
```

In the above query I need to take the value where `TYPE` is based on `'TECHNIQUE' where KEY1__c` should be matched to `DATA1__c` from the outer query.

The query is very similar to this example

```
 SELECT Id 
     FROM Idea 
     WHERE ((Idea.Title LIKE 'Vacation%') 
         AND (CreatedDate > YESTERDAY)  
         AND (Id IN (SELECT ParentId 
                     FROM Vote 
                     WHERE CreatedById = '005x0000000sMgYAAU'))
```

The only difference is that `IN` clause is used with a different object.
In my query I'm trying to use `IN` clause from the same object parameters.

Kindly let me know in case of any further clarifications.

Comment: @Arun please post your `SOQL` query

Comment: @Pavel i already given my SOQL query. The above one on the parameter object, kindly let me know in case of any further calrifications

Comment: @Arun sorry for misunderstanding, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
List<String> pereTechniqueParams = new List<String>();
for (String key: 
          [SELECT KEY1__c FROM Parameters__c WHERE TYPE__c = 'PERE_TECHNIQUE']) {
    pereTechniqueParams.add(key.KEY1__c);
}

List<Parameters__c> params = [SELECT DATA1__c, TEXT__c 
                                  FROM PARAMETERS__c 
                                  WHERE (TYPE__c = 'ADMINISTRATEUR' 
                                         AND KEY1__c LIKE 'MONTAGE%' 
                                         AND KEY2__c = '') 
                                      AND DATA1__c IN:pereTechniqueParams];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
for (Parameters__c key1 : [SELECT KEY1__c 
                    FROM Parameters__c WHERE TYPE__c = 'PERE_TECHNIQUE']) {
    pereTechniqueParams.add(key1.KEY1__c);
}
```

Don't use String use Parameters__c

```
public class LookUpController {
    public List<Parameters__c> getParamters() {
        List<String> pereTechniqueParams = new List<String>();
        for (Parameters__c key1 : [SELECT KEY1__c 
                            FROM Parameters__c WHERE TYPE__c = 'PERE_TECHNIQUE']) {
            pereTechniqueParams.add(key1.KEY1__c);
        } 
        List<Parameters__c> params = [SELECT DATA1__c, TEXT__c 
                               FROM PARAMETERS__c 
                               WHERE TYPE__c = 'ADMINISTRATEUR' 
                                   AND KEY1__c LIKE 'MONTAGE%' 
                                   AND KEY2__c = '' 
                                   AND Data1__c IN: pereTechniqueParams];
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks a lot for your quick reply and i understood how to do subquery for the same object. I try implement the solution given by you. But i getting an Error: LookUpController Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String at line 29 column 41 which is near key.KEY1__c what is this problem? could you help me

Comment: public class LookUpController{
    
    public List<Parameters__c> getParamters(){
       
    List<String> pereTechniqueParams = new List<String>();
     
    for (String key1: [SELECT KEY1__c FROM  Parameters__c WHERE             TYPE__c = 'PERE_TECHNIQUE']){                 pereTechniqueParams.add(paramKey1.KEY1__c);
      }
      
      List<String> params = [SELECT DATA1__c, TEXT__c FROM PARAMETERS__c WHERE TYPE__c = 'ADMINISTRATEUR' AND KEY1__c LIKE 'MONTAGE%' AND KEY2__c = '' AND Data1__c IN:pereTechniqueParams ]; 
     
      
      return params;
       
    }
    
}

Comment: @Arun you use `paramKey1` which is not exist instead the loop variable `key1`. See update in answer.

Comment: Hi Pavel, Sorry i have given it wrong. I used Key1 only. Still I'm getting the issue.

Comment: Hi Pavel, still i'm getting this Error: LookUpController Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: String at line 30 column 41 at this line pereTechniqueParams.add(key1.PARAM_KEY1__c);

Comment: Arun post LookUpController

Comment: got to know the error, here we used the String key1 but it should be the sObject  Parameters__c now the compile error is gone.

Comment: Sorry for it, it's my typo

Answer (score 1):

The Vote Id and Idea Id is not same, The inner selection return list of Vote, And there is not result for sub-query `Id IN (SELECT ParentId  FROM Vote....`

Channge Code To

```
set<Id> ideaIdSet = new set<Id>();
for(Vote vote : [SELECT ParentId FROM Vote WHERE CreatedById = '005x0000000sMgYAAU']){
    ideaIdSet.add(vote.ParentId);
} 

SELECT Id 
     FROM Idea 
     WHERE ((Title LIKE 'Vacation%') 
         AND (CreatedDate > YESTERDAY)  
         AND (Id IN ideaIdSet)
```

Comment: I never asked question on the example query it just for an understanding i have given it and already it works fine. my question is on the above query on parameters object. Thanks advance for the answer. Kindly let me know in case of any further clarification.